Скил или скилл?
Как правильно пишется: "скил" или "скилл"?
Хотим применить это слово в названии будущей компании, но, увы, не знаем, какое из написаний всё же верное.
Спасибо.

https://companies.rbc.ru/id/1197746648813-obschestvo-s-ogranichennoj-otvetstvennostyu-skilfektori/

Вот этот форум подчеркивает красным "скилы". А скиллы разрешает.

Спасибо Всем за ответы большое! Подскажите, что это за форум, где его можно увидеть?

На подобный вопрос уже отвечала "Грамота.ру" (см. вопрос № 299311):
№ 299311

Здравствуйте. Я уже задавала этот вопрос ранее, но ответа пока нет.
Как правильно по-русски писать слово "скил" в значении "навык"? В
интернете встречается несколько вариантов написания слова в
единственном числе (скил, скилл, скилла) и во множественном (скилы,
скиллы, скилс, скилсы). Какие варианты стоит считать верными?

Ответ

Нормативной рекомендации пока что нет, однако предпочтительно
написание с одной Л: скил, скилы.


Спасибо большое за ответ!
